# jquery timepicker with auto update MVC web forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myPicker').timepicker({
        'step': '15',
        'minTime': '8:00am',
        'maxTime': '17:30pm',
        'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
    }); 

    $('.myTimepicker').on('changeTime', function() {
        $('#mySpan').text($(this).val());
    });     
});
```

This is my MVC View page

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <td>
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].From, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control myPicker" } })
    </td>
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how do I automatically fill out web forms(start from, time) when page first loading. I am using @model IList
 [image: My result]

This is my code but this jQuery will not work for me.

Comment: Not clear what you problem is. What is the type of property `From` and does it have values when you pass it to the view. What is the relevance if the 2nd script to your question? And which jquery plugin are you using?

Comment: Yes, values pass it to the view , I am using jquery.timepicker.js

Comment: But most importantly, what is the property type? And a link to the plugin might be useful

Comment: The property 'From' string. How can I link to the plugin?

Comment: Is [this the one](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker) your using?

Comment: And an you show an example of the html your generating (in particular the `value` attribute

Comment: Yes only start from (m[].From)

Comment: Still not sure what you problem is. If your generating `<input name="[0].From" ... value="6.30pm" />` then 6.30pm will be selected when you first generate the view.

Comment: I need to, when page load time automatically fill start from with time. My existing form will only display mouse over date dropdown list .

Comment: Still not clear (why wont you show a sample of your html?). If your property has a value that is valid, then it will be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a separate `<span id="mySpan-@i"></span>` for each timepicker to track each picker's changes. Then add a data attribute to your input elements: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].From, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control myPicker", data_id = i } })`. Then in your JavaScript code you'll have:

```
$(function () {
    var timePickers = $('.myPicker');

    timePickers.each(function () {
        var currentTimePicker = $(this)

        currentTimePicker.timepicker({
            'step': '15',
            'minTime': '8:00am',
            'maxTime': '17:30pm',
            'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
        });

        currentTimePicker.on('changeTime', function () {
            var id = currentTimePicker.data('id');
            $('#mySpan-' + id).text($(this).val());
        });

        $('#mySpan-' + currentTimePicker.data('id')).text(currentTimePicker.val());
    });        
});
```

Comment: I am not clear about your code what do I have to add { <your-code-here> } ??

Comment: You've set the onchange callback for your timepicker but you now have to set what the value of the span should be when the timepicker is loaded. So you should put `$('#mySpan').text($(this).val());` in `<your-code-here>` placeholder.

Comment: But I changed to code $(document).ready(function () 
{
  $('.myPicker').timepicker(
   {
   'step': '15',
   'minTime': '8:00am',
   'maxTime': '17:30pm',
   'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
   }
  );   

  $('.myPicker').load(function () { $('#mySpan').text($(this).val()); });
}); but still not working

Comment: Hello, This is my sample Html code <link href="jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <div class="example"> 
 <input id="myPicker" class="time" type="text" /></div>
</body> but even jQuery script not working.

Comment: You mean that jQuery is not working at all? Are you sure you have referenced it correctly in your <script> tag?

Comment: Yes I did copy your code and past. It'll display empty text box after load html page.

Comment: If you are using layout page, you should put the code in a section like this: `@section scripts { <the-code-in-script-tags-here> }`

Comment: Yes, I have already added @section scripts to my View page. But I added Html and jQuery still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90018/discussion-between-vladislav-karamfilov-and-rob).